# Bottom Border Width on Swift TextField in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, border, textfield

i builded a static tableview with more Rowes than the screen has, so the user has to scroll to see all cell.

Every cell has a textfield with the following class to add a bottom border:

```
class TextFieldWithBottomBorder: UITextField {
   let border = CALayer()
   let width = CGFloat(1.0)

   func addBottomBorder(color: UIColor){
       self.border.borderColor = color.cgColor
       self.border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height:self.frame.size.height)

       self.border.borderWidth = self.width
       self.layer.addSublayer(self.border)
       self.layer.masksToBounds = true
   }

   func changeBorderColor(color: UIColor){
       self.border.borderColor = color.cgColor
   }
}
```

And i call the method after receiving some data from the server e. g.

```
self.firstnameTextField.text = firstNameFromDB
self.firstnameTextField.addBottomBorder(color: .blue)
```

This works fine for every cell is currently displayed. But the cells which are out of the current view the with is shorter than the textfield.
See this screenshot, for "Vorname", means firstName everything looks good, but for email, password etc. the border is to short.
http://share-your-photo.com/34b5e80253

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the size of the UITextField is being resized after you have called addBottomBorder and so the UIView being used at the line is now not wide enough.  It's difficult to say why this would be without seeing more code but there are several methods you could use to overcome it.

1) Switch to a UIView instead of a CALayer and use auto layout to keep the view in the correction position.

2) Override layoutSubviews to update the frame of the bottom line.

The simplest for you is probably option 2 (although I would go option 1) and it would look like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.size.height - width, width:  self.frame.size.width, height:self.frame.size.height)
}
```

Now whenever the frame/size of the text field changes the frame/size of the border line CALayer will be updated appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Use this class for bottom line text field

```
@IBDesignable class BottomTextField: UITextField {
    var lineView = UIView()

 @IBInspectable var lineViewBgColor:UIColor = UIColor.gray{
        didSet {
            if !isFirstResponder {
                lineView.backgroundColor = lineViewBgColor
            }
        }
    }
required init?(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder:aDecoder)!
        setup()
    }

    override init(frame:CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        setup()
    }

    // MARK:- Private Methods
    private func setup() {
        lineView.frame = CGRect(x:CGFloat(0), y:self.frame.size.height-2, width:self.frame.size.width, height:CGFloat(1))
        lineView.backgroundColor = lineViewBgColor

        self.addSubview(lineView)
    }

}
```

Comment: While this is possibly a better way of doing it it will suffer the same problem as the frame of the bottom line is only set when it is created so if the text field changes frame the bottom line will not reflect the change.